# Regex: find numbers greater than specific value (with varying decimal lengths)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to regex find all values in a list that are greater than or equal to .03.  The tricky part is that my values have between 9 and 15 decimal places.

My current code works somewhat but is unwieldy - any advice much appreciated:

```
^(?:0?\.[0-9][3-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|0?\.[0-9][3-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|0?\.[0-9][3-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])$
```

Thank you.

Comment: I see your regex the same as `^0?\.[0-9][3-9]\d{9,11}$`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an asterisk to denote zero or more of a digit:

```
^(?:0?\.\d[3-9]\d*)$
```

This has the added benefit of matching exactly `0.03` or something with (say) 100 decimal places.

If you want to be strict about the decimal places, you can use brace syntax, which matches any repetitions between 9 and 15 digits:

```
^(?:0?\.\d[3-9]\d{9,15})$
```

Note that, as written, this regex doesn't match anything greater than or equal to 0.03--it matches anything greater than or equal to 0.03 and less than 1, and it doesn't match, say, 0.1, which is greater than 0.03. To match anything greater than 0.03, best to skip regex entirely and parse the number.

Comment: thank you for your response!  Apologies, but I am confused at the last sentence - why would it not match .01 if it matches everything greater than .03 and less than 1?

Comment: Because `\.\d[3-9]` is not optional, so it won't match `0.1` because that string fails the `[3-9]` character.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply parse your data as `float`:

From your pattern you seem to have the numbers already seperated very well - why use regex at all? You numbers fill the whole line or aren't matched at all ( `r"^........$"` so essentially you have:

```
t = """0.0000002
0.4
0.04
0.004
24544.23354
Also Bad"""
```

Simply split into lines and check each line as float

```
# splits the string into a list of lines
for line in (x.strip() for x in t.split("\n")):
    try:
        if float(line) >= 0.03:
            print(line)
        else: 
            print("Not ok:",line)
    except:
        print("Not ok:",line)
```

Output:

```
Not ok: 0.0000002
0.4
0.04
Not ok: 0.004
24544.23354
Not ok: Also Bad
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:    0.030000000  -  0.999999999999999

***Greater than or equal to .03 and less than 1.0

at 9-15 decimal places***

```
0?\.(?:03\d{7,13}|0[4-9]\d{7,13}|[1-9]\d{8,14})
```

Expanded

```
 #  0.030000000  -  0.999999999999999
 0?
 \.
 (?:
      03 \d{7,13} 
   |  0 [4-9] \d{7,13} 
   |  [1-9] \d{8,14} 
 )
```

Note - this was machine generated, there could be some overlap.
Example:  `0?\.(?:0[3-9]\d{7,13}|[1-9]\d{8,14})`